# How to USE Soft IME with DPAD

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, d-pad

We have standard software IME keyboard , 
SoftIME work fine for touch 
How we can naviagate on SOft IME using DPAD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DPAD to simulate touch event(MotionEvent) MOVE/DOWN/UP, reaction on Key UP, so user can see focus while MOVE and DOWN.

Comment: from where (module) i should simulate the touch events ?

Comment: You can also reference OpenWnn [http://www.codeforge.com/article/204267](http://www.codeforge.com/article/204267), if you are able to modify the framework level, normal hardware keyboard event will pass though PhoneWindowManager interceptKeyBeforeQueueing and interceptKeyBeforeDispatching

Comment: All hardware key event will pass though PhoneWindowManager interceptKeyBeforeQueueing and interceptKeyBeforeDispatching, you can transform hardware key event to touch event

Comment: touch event requires x,y coordinates , which coordinates should I use ?

Comment: I used to give a fixed value to x, y, your keyboard size must be fixed